# Pandoc, markdown to pdf doesn't wrap long words in paragraphs

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc, xelatex

I'm trying to generate a clean PDF from markdown using Pandoc and xelatex.

When I convert :

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I end up having :

[image: overflown text]

Here is the command I use to generate the PDF :

```
/usr/local/bin/pandoc --verbose \
--chapters --from=markdown+yaml_metadata_block -S \
--latex-engine=xelatex \
--listings -H listings-setup.tex \
--template template.pdf \
--toc --chapters \
-o test.pdf \
metadata.yml \
test.md
```

I use the document class : **report**

I have tried different things from inside the template and the extra header I'm using but I have now idea what template is Pandoc using when generating paragraphs.

I see under my template.pdf (extracted from Pandoc), but doesn't seem to apply here :

```
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
```

Comment: this seems more like a latex question... you can get the template pandoc uses with `pandoc -D latex`...

Comment: Edited the question, I actually did that too but it seems to me that this template is not used to render paragraphs ?

Comment: try `-s -o test.tex` instead of `-o test.pdf` and then debug the generated LaTeX...

Comment: I see this *Overfull \hbox (470.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 131--132
\EU1/lmr/m/n/10 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa*

Comment: see https://www.google.com/search?q=latex+force+break+long+words

Answer (score 1):

You've a few possibilities. Since pandoc uses LaTeX for PDF generation, these are [adapted from this LaTeX answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121832/breaking-words-at-the-end-of-line):

1. Annotate the proper language:

   ```
   ---
   lang: en-GB
   ---

   rest of document
   ```
2. use [soft hyphens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) inside a word to explicitly denote the allowed places to break. You can either use the unicode character or the HTML entity `&shy;` which pandoc will convert automatically for LaTeX etc. For example; `cryp&shy;to&shy;graphy`
3. Specify exceptions via `\hyphenation{cryp-to-graphy}`